# Image cropping with scrollbar - JQuery Issue on Mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I am developing Asp.net (C#) webpage. That is accessing on mobile. 
The image is to be displayed in ASP Image control with scrollbar. After that cropping is need to crop the image. The code is

```
<asp:Image ID="imgCrop" runat="server" />
```

For the scrollbar, external Jquery was used (Overflow & panel scrollbar were not supported in mobile)

```
 $(function () {
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    });
```

I am using  **"jquery.Jcrop.js""** JQuery for image cropping and assign the contol as like this

```
      jQuery('#imgCrop').Jcrop({

        onSelect: storeCoords
    });
```

Here, below code is used for display asp.net image with JScrollbar

```
            <div class="scroll-pane">
           <asp:Image ID="imgCrop" runat="server" />                   
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.scroll-pane{
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

I am used above all code. I can able see the scrollbar in mobile. Once upload the image, the scrollbar is showing. The problem is about when **I am trying to move the scrollbar, Cropping is take place instead of scroll the image**. I think to JQuery get overlapped. How to resolve this issue?